Laravel Route Parameter Issue: Missing required parameter for [Route: edit_mahasiswa]
I'm encountering an issue with Laravel routing in my application. Specifically, I'm getting the following error:
Internal Server Error
Illuminate\Routing\Exceptions\UrlGenerationException
Missing required parameter for [Route: edit_mahasiswa] [URI: mahasiswa/edit/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].

I have a route defined for editing a Mahasiswa entity:
route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:user']], function () {
 Route::get('/mahasiswa/edit/{id}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'edit'])->name('edit_mahasiswa');
}

This is my Controller
public function edit($id) {
        //dd($id);
        $mahasiswa = Mahasiswa::find($id);
        if ($mahasiswa) {
            return view('mahasiswa.edit', compact('mahasiswa'));
        } else {
            Alert::error('Mahasiswa tidak ditemukan');
            return redirect()->route('daftar_mahasiswa')->with('error', 'Mahasiswa tidak ditemukan');
            
        }
    }

In my view where I list Mahasiswa entities, I am trying to generate a URL for editing an entity:
@foreach ($mahasiswa as $m)
<tr>
    <th scope="row">{{ $m->id }}</th>
    <td>{{ $m->nim }}</td>
    <td>{{ $m->name }}</td>
    <td>{{ $m->email }}</td>
    <td>
        <a href="{{ route('edit_mahasiswa', ['id' => $m->id]) }}">
            <button class="btn btn-warning">
                <i class="ri-edit-2-fill"></i>
            </button>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
@endforeach


However, I am getting an error that says:
Missing required parameter for [Route: edit_mahasiswa] [URI: mahasiswa/edit/{id}] [Missing parameter: id].


What I Have Tried:

Verified that the route is correctly defined in web.php.
Ensured that the id parameter is present and not null in the view.
Added debugging information in the edit method of the controller to check if the parameter is being received.
Cleared route and config caches using php artisan route:clear, php artisan config:clear, etc.
Checked file permissions and .htaccess settings.
Used url() and action() functions to generate URLs but encountered the same issue.


are you sure $m->id is not giving you NULL in some cases?

Can you specify how did you access this route edit_mahasiswa. ?Since it is UrlGenerationException there is a possibility thatid is not passed properly during accessing this route.

when i dd to my controller it works but if i run my code to return view missing the parameter

I have verified that $m->id is being passed correctly by using dd() in the controller method. The output confirms that id is received.

Despite these steps, I am still encountering the UrlGenerationException error indicating that the id parameter is missing when trying to generate the URL for the edit_mahasiswa route.

"by using dd()" - dd() is not a reliable way to debug a loop... You're doing a foreach(), so dd($m->id) will only show you the id of the first instance of $m. If you do ['id' => $m->id ?? 1], does your code work? If so, then one or more instances of $m doesn't have an id property, and ['id' => null] is invalid, and you need to handle this.

"In my view where I list Mahasiswa entities" - Show this code; I assume you're querying your DB for Mahasiswa records, then passing them to this view and looping them via the foreach(). There should be no reason $m->id is null, since DB records need a primary key, which I assume is id... But yeah, you're missing an important piece of code here that we need to see to help further.

The issue is probably because the $m->id returns in null and it is passing null value to a required parameter. You can verify it by just passing null statically and passing an integer value.
<a href="{{ route('edit_mahasiswa', ['id' => null]) }}">Button</a> //for error
<a href="{{ route('edit_mahasiswa', ['id' => 1]) }}">Button</a> // for correct results

You can fix it by making sure that $m->id is never null or make the parameter optional with  {id?}.
Route::get('/mahasiswa/edit/{id?}', [MahasiswaController::class, 'edit'])-`>name('edit_mahasiswa');`

But then make sure to handle the null case in your controller.

thankyou for the answer so how i handle my controller to make it works sorry for my bad english

You can simply give a default value to the $id variable.

`public function edit($id = 0) {
//your code
}`

or just give it null value by default
public function edit($id = 0) {  //your code }

thankyou it works used {id?}

You should really look into why $m->id is null... If these are Database records you're trying to edit, they should all have an id, since that should be the primary key. {id?} makes the property optional on that route, so you could navigate to /mahasiswa/edit or mahasiswa/edit/1, but the 1st route doesn't make sense... What record are you trying to edit if you don't pass an ID? This is a bandaid on a bigger problem with your code.

You don't need to put your id as array.
Just put your id like this
<a href="{{ route('edit_mahasiswa', $m->id) }}">


Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
